# iframe with jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe

has anyone ever had a webpage with an iframe in it that used jquery? My main page that contains the iframe includes jquery with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
```

and it has no javascript errors. My iframe includes jquery the same way and if I load it by itself it also has no javascript errors. However when I load my main page with the iframe in it I get two errors

> Error: c.defaultView.getComputedStyle(h, null) is null
>   Source File: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js
>   Line: 16

and

> Error: $ is not defined
>   Source File: http://myiframe.php
>   Line: 23

if it is just plain javascript in the iframe it works fine

Comment: Have you tried an alternate URL for the `<script>` inside of your `<iframe>`? Like the [`min` version](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js)?

Comment: I also tried <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script> and I got the same error but the source file was the jquery-1.5.2.min.js file so I know its happening in the iframe not in the main page

Comment: What browser is this happening on?

Comment: Are you putting html inside the iframe, or are you using a src attribute?

Comment: good question.. actually I'm testing in firefox because of all the addons for web developers and I didn't check any other browser yet.. It turns out it works fine in Safari for Mac

Comment: @wewals I'm using the src attribute

Comment: Is the src pointing at something on the same domain as the parent document?

Comment: @wewals yes both the main page and the iframe are from the same domain

Comment: Have you tried hosting the .js locally?

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure (? erm...) that if you are using JQUERY on the same domain, you do not need to load it a second time in the page that you are loading in the iFrame. You can just load it in the parent page once.

I know that you probably need to have it available when you are testing the page in isolation (ie not in the iFrame) but you can disable the `<script>` tag before you publish.

I've had terrible problems making javascript traverse iFrames into the main parent document and back to the iframe again (in general) and recall having to do things like `parent.document` just to get the js to talk together.

You may want to consider loading the contents of the same domain page into a (scrolling) `<div>` using jquery `.load()`, which again avoids having to reload all your javascripts and CSS if you've already done that on the parent page. I've found this to be quite useful at times.